# How to copy files from GitHub workflow to Amazon EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, github-actions, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I'm using AWS ECS fargate. I need to use volumes to store some files on container.
But Fargate is serverless then there is no storage. I found EFS is solution to using volume for fargate.

I faced github workflow not copy files to EFS...
The github runner has files well, but below codes not work. I expected below codes copy files to EFS or fargate container.

github workflow, it runs on runner. I searched this way from chat GPT.

```
      - name: Copy source code to EFS
        run: |
          aws --version

          sudo mkdir /flask
          sudo mkdir /nginx
          sudo mkdir /nginx/log

          # Copy source code files to EFS (assuming EFS is mounted at /efs_mount_point)
          sudo cp -R ./flask/* /flask
          sudo cp -R ./nginx/* /var/log/nginx
          sudo cp -R ./ /

          ls -Rl /flask
          ls -Rl /nginx
          ls -Rl /nginx/log
```

My scenario:

1. copy files from github runner to fargate container
2. copy commands in task definition copy files from container to EFS
3. finally fargate find files and read them from EFS

I'm confusing the flows of copy files.

Container is running but that can not find files so not found error raised then terminate.. so I can not enter terminal of fargate container.

I tried enter EC2 terminal that mounted EFS and checked EFS dir. There are only directories those I set path on access points not files...

EFS access point

[image]

task definition

[image]

[image]

Please let me know how to copy source code files to EFS, I need some files that read by container.

---

Updated

```
      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        run: |
          export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
          docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yaml build

          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_FLASK_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_NGINX_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG

          echo "::set-output name=flask_image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_FLASK_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
          echo "::set-output name=nginx_image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_NGINX_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
          
      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: flask-task-def
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: fargate-task.json
          container-name: flask
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.flask_image }}

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: nginx-task-def
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.flask-task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
          container-name: nginx
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.nginx_image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.flask-task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: service
          cluster: cluster
          codedeploy-deployment-group: g
          codedeploy-appspec: appspec.yaml
          wait-for-service-stability: true
```

appspec.yaml

```yaml
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:xx:task-definition/fargate-task:35"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "nginx"
          ContainerPort: 80
        PlatformVersion: "LATEST"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That GitHub Action code in your question is just copying files around on the GitHub runner server. It isn't connected to EFS at all.

I can think of two options for accessing EFS from a GitHub runner:

- Enable [AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/using-aws-transfer-integration.html) for SFTP access to your EFS volume, then use an SFTP action in GitHub. However this is going to cost over $200 a month just to have SFTP enabled.
- Create an EC2 instance with the EFS volume mapped to it, and configure GitHub to use that EC2 instance as your GitHub runner, and expose the EFS volume mapping to the

---

The way you are copying code from your GitHub repository to EFS volumes that your containers will later use is not a typical setup. Typically you would build a new Docker image in your GitHub Action that includes that updated source code, and push the image to your AWS ECR repository. Then you would trigger a redeploy of your ECS/Fargate service.

Comment: I'm using docker build, and push images to ECR on workflow, But container can not find files... That's why I tried to copy files to EFS.

Do you mean just build and push images to ECR and deploy task definition are enough to copy files to fargate container?

Comment: I wrote workflow, appspec in my question. Please check this.

Comment: When I logged "ls -R" in entryPoint of task definition.json then "." is result.. no files in home dir(?). I think it's because container is fargate.

Comment: Why do you think a Fargate container's default path is a home directory? That would depend entirely on the Dockerfile the container was built from. Also, it's not going to be an EFS volume at that path.